# Old VB6 app failed to login for user 'sa' during insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, ado

first time poster here.

So, I have this old VB6 software that has decided to break during an insert on a table, returning the error "Login Failed for user 'sa'". However, this error takes a while to happen, after an undetermined amount of inserts have already happened.

All these inserts are NOT occurring during a transaction. And said table is not a temporary table(declared with # or ##), nor a view. There are other places in the app that makes much more use of the database/connection. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2, connecting via ADO.

Any thoughts on where or what the error might be? Is it a problem with the app? Is it a problem with the database?

UPDATE: Here is the part of the code that does the inserts

```
//gAdoVIN is our ADODB.Connection object, it opens once (when the app starts) and closes once (when the app closes)
For iRow = 1 To grdItens.LinhasPreenchidas - 1 //runs about 400~1000 times
    Dim sEstab() As String
    sEstab = Split(grdItens.TextMatrixO(iRow, iColCdEstab), ",")
    For iSplit = 0 To UBound(sEstab)
        If sEstab(iSplit) <> "" Then            
            GsSql = "Some query here"
            //b_SqlADO Opens records, and dispose it if necessary
            b_SqlADO GsSql, gAdoVIN, rcCot
            Do While Not rcCot.EOF //runs about 3 times
                GsSql = "Insert into " & sTabTemp & " (Some Fields) values (Some Values)"
                gAdoVIN_Execute GsSql //fails here after a while
                rcCot.MoveNext
             Loop

             cVlr = grdItens.TextMatrixO(iRow, iColValor) + ((grdItens.TextMatrixO(iRow, iColValor) * sicrAcrs_RelcSem) / 100)
             GsSql = "Some other query"
             b_SqlADO GsSql, gAdoVIN, rcTemp
             If rcTemp.EOF Then
                 rcTemp.AddNew
             End If
             //Updates some fields
             rcTemp.Update
        End If
    Next iSplit
Next iRow
```

And the code for gAdoVIN_Execute

```
Public Sub gAdoVIN_Execute(sSql As String, Optional ByRef lRecordsAffected_LOG As Long = 0, Optional lOptions_LOG As Long = -1)
    //Some Log Operation

    //here is where the insert is executed
    gAdoVIN.EXECUTE sSql, lRecordsAffected_LOG, lOptions_LOG 

    //Another Log Operation
End Sub
```

UPDATE 2: When an inserts fails and returns the error, running it again without doing anything else does not fail. It was a workaround so it didn't solve the issue entirely, just made it work for now.

Comment: Does it always fail on the same record? How are you generating the SQL used?

Comment: No it is not always on the same record. It is generated in a loop, reading data from a MSFlexGrid, basically "INSERT INTO TABLE (Fields) VALUES (Values)". The loop runs aprox. 400~1000 times, and for each time, about 3 inserts are made, I did notice that if I run the exact same loop about 100 times, the error does not occur.

Comment: Instead of doing insert into...values, can you try preparing the statement first and then, in your loop, just execute the prepared statement? Do the inserts still fail? Also read a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962296/vb6-adodb-connection-string-to-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Are you disposing of your objects correctly? If you are doing lots of inserts the command objects build up in memory and can then cause it to fail. Do you have the code to run the inserts?

Comment: I updated the post with the code used to runs the inserts. I like your idea that objects are not being disposed correctly, makes sense to me.